# MessageProducer doesn't send the message when migrating from ActiveMQ Classic 5.7.0 to 5.18.3

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to migrate an existing code from `org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0` to `org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.18.3`. Here there are the dependencies updated:

```xml
<!--dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The code sends a topic to the different system and a third one consumes it.
The receiving end has been already updated to the 5.18.3 version (and the communication is working when sending topics using the activemq-core library).

Here's the code:

```java
public static boolean sendTopic(String brokerUrl, String topicName, String clientId) {
    boolean succeed = false;
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(brokerUrl) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(topicName)) {
        LOG.info("Broker Url: {}", brokerUrl);
        LOG.info("Topic Name: {}", topicName);
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            // Producer
            LOG.info("Creating connection...");
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
            //LOG.info("Adding the url to the connection factory");
            //connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);

            String id = AEM_TOPIC_ID;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(clientId)) {
                id = id + "-" + clientId;
                LOG.info("ClientId {}", id);
            }
            LOG.info("Connection Factory {}", connectionFactory);
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            LOG.info("Connection {}", connection);
            connection.setClientID(id);
            LOG.info("Starting connection . . .");
            connection.start();
            LOG.info("Connection started");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicName);
            LOG.info("Topic created: {}", topic);
            // Publish
            String payload = "AEM Topic - " + topicName;
            LOG.info("Sending text '{}'", payload);
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
            LOG.debug("Creating the Publisher. . .");
            MessageProducer publisher = session.createProducer(topic);
            LOG.debug("Publisher is sending. . . Publisher: {}. Session: {}",publisher, session);
            publisher.send(msg, PERSISTENT, DEFAULT_PRIORITY, DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE);
            LOG.debug("Closing Session");
            session.close();
            LOG.debug("Session closed");
            succeed = true;
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred during topic sending", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception not handler occurred in sendTopic method", e);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    LOG.debug("Closing connection.");
                    connection.close();
                    LOG.info("Connection closed.");
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    LOG.error("Failed to close connection", e);
                }
                LOG.info("Reaching the end of the method: {}",succeed);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(brokerUrl)) {
            LOG.error("BrokerUrl is empty");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(topicName)) {
            LOG.error("Topic Name is empty");
        }
    }
    LOG.info("Reaching the end of the method: {}",succeed);
    return succeed;
}
```

Looking at the logs I've noticed that the `publisher.send` breaks, but there is no log on it, and it doesn't enter any of the `catch` blocks. It goes directly to the `finally` block. Here the logs about this part:

```
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Topic Name: yyy.aem.ports.en
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Creating connection...
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber ClientId AEM-TOPIC-ID-ports-en
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Connection Factory org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory@78543156
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Connection ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:yyy.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1,clientId=null,started=false}
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Starting connection . . .
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Connection started
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Topic created: topic://yyy.aem.ports.en
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Sending text 'AEM Topic - yyy.aem.ports.en'
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Creating the Publisher. . .
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Publisher is sending. . . Publisher: ActiveMQMessageProducer { value=ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1:1 }. Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1,started=true,closed=false} java.lang.Object@63505d63
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Closing connection.
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Connection closed.
com.xxx.common.feature.core.jms.JmsDurableSubscriber Reaching the end of the method: false
```

There is another log to usually check in these cases and it is related to the `org.apache.activemq`.

Here the logs that appear there

```
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@592ce40e[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Reconnect was triggered but transport is not started yet. Wait for start to connect the transport.
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Started unconnected
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Waking up reconnect task
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport urlList connectionList:[tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100], from: [tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100]
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Attempting 0th connect to: tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=0, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100, MaxFrameSizeEnabled=true, ProviderVersion=null}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Connection established
*INFO* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=104857600, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, MaxFrameSizeEnabled=true, ProviderVersion=5.18.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, maxFrameSizeEnabled=true}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=104857600, maxFrameSizeEnabled=true}
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext Begin:TX:ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1 Transaction Rollback, txid:TX:ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext Rollback: TX:ID:xxx.it-34534-1705588843383-15:1:1 syncCount: 0
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@326a2abc[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 0.000 seconds.
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Stopped tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@592ce40e[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport Stopping transport tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@57214
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3010317a[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport Closed socket Socket[addr=xxx.it/yyy,port=61616,localport=57214]
*DEBUG* [EventAdminThread #18] org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3010317a[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

I tried briefly to remove the `finally` block to check if an error would show, but aside the obvious exception for the `connection` not closed I just got a warn with a `null` `EOFException` in the latter log.

Here the logs about the exception/warn that appeared in the org.apache.activemq log:

```
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Connection established
*INFO* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59858] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=104857600, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, MaxFrameSizeEnabled=true, ProviderVersion=5.18.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59858] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59858 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, maxFrameSizeEnabled=true}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59858] org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59858 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=104857600, maxFrameSizeEnabled=true}
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59856] org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport Stopping transport tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59856
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59856] org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d4c7b8[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport Closed socket Socket[addr=xxx/yyy,port=61616,localport=59856]
*DEBUG* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59856] org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d4c7b8[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
*WARN* [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://xxx.it/yyy:61616@59856] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport Transport (tcp://xxx.it:61616?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100) failed, attempting to automatically reconnect
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:280) [common-features.core:1.4.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) [common-features.core:1.4.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) [common-features.core:1.4.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) [common-features.core:1.4.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried to reinstall the version before the migration and the topics were sent correctly. I'm very confused on what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, i updated and added the log. I have no control or visibility on the other side unfortunately.
About the migration yes, i basically just changed the libraries in the POM document. Also Added those.

Comment: Yes, i added the dependencies mentioned above and removed the activemq-core dependency. Only on this (client) application. The receiver end is not controlled by us so we have no visibility on that. The code on this end was not touched.
To be honest i thought i needed both dependencies to send the topic. Good to know, my bad. I removed the dependency for the broker, built it but it still doesn't work (no change in the logs either).

Comment: So you're trying to use the 5.18.3 client with the 5.7.0 broker? What leads you to believe that will actually work?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need a dependency on `org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.11` either. That's a transitive dependency of `org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.18.3` that will be included automatically.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Sorry, i'm trying to understand, so if the 2 systems are not both updated they can't communicate? Meaning that the connection from the new library won't work while the receiving system has the older library?
For the hawtbuf library i thought it was needed because i got some exceptions because of it. I'll try it again, thanks

Comment: I've checked with the system i'm communicating with. they updated it to the 5.18.3 version too, so that shoudn't be a problem in theory.

Comment: What have you done to resolve the problem? Any additional info would be helpful. Did the client or the broker upgrade first? Does the 5.7.0 client work with a 5.18.3 broker? I'm trying to isolate where the problem is - the broker or the client.

Comment: The receiving end seems to be working. We have 3 different environments and for what they told me they already updated their ends to the 5.18.3 version. 
So the activemq-core 5.7.0 (my side on higher envs) is sending correctly to the 5.18.3 on their receiving side.

Comment: You need to add all these details to your question. Folks shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand the problem. Please update your question with all the latest information. Thanks!